# How to check for null condition on shared variable in crystal reports?

Tags: crystal-reports, null, formula

I am using a

```
shared datevar tdate;
```

shared variable (setting in a subreport) in a formula field.
how can I check for its null values as

```
IsNull(tdate)
```

is not working. its says a field is required to IsNull function.
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the variables are declared but uninitialized then they will contain the following default values:

- Number: 0
- Currency: $0
- String: "" //The empty string
- Date: Date(0,0,0) //The null date value
- Time: None or null //The isnull() function won't work
- Datetime: None or null //The isnull() function won't work

[Source](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.doc.crdesigner/reportdesigner/crcondefaultvaluesforsimpletypescrystalsyntax.htm)

With that being said, you shouldn't use or check for default values in code. Instead, initialize them to a default value of your own. For example:

`shared datevar tdate := date(1900,1,1) //Initialize the shared variable`

`... if tdate=date(1900,1,1) then ... //check for initialized and unmodified value`

Comment: It's a shame that CR's custom-function feature doesn't support an object type so that one could create a single `isDefault()` function...

Answer (score 1):

You can only use the `Isnull()` function on fields.

I'm not sure if this will work, but it's worth a try:

- Create a formula field:

  ```
  // {@wrapper}
  Shared Datevar tdate;
  ```
- Test it for null:

  ```
  If IsNull({@wrapper}) Then
   ...
  ```

Comment: thanks for reply. actually I am doing the same thing and receiving an error message.